# Why is it that no bipartite graphs contain a triangle?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I know it has something to do with the vertices belonging to two differnt sets without intersection but I'm not exactly sure of a concrete explanation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have a bipartition $(A,B)$ of the graph, where $A,B$ are independent sets of vertices. Suppose the vertices $\{x,y,z\}$ form a triangle. How can these vertices be distributed between $A$ and $B$? By cardinality either $A$ or $B$ must contain at least two vertices from the triangle; let's say it is $A$. However, any pair of vertices in the triangle have an edge between them, contradicting the fact that $A$ is independent. Thus a bipartite graph cannot contain a triangle.

Answer (score 2):

Bipartite graphs are 2-colorable, but a triangle requires three colors.